# Impossible to add any dependency to build.sbt

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

I'm pretty new to playframework and a got some questions.
We are using the 2.4.6 version.
First one is : How do you add dependency ? 
I want to add `mockito-core` so i got this `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1205-jdbc42" 
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.commons" % "commons-csv" % "1.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.drewnoakes" % "metadata-extractor" % "2.7.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "3.0.0-M1"
libraryDependencie += "org.mockito" %% "mockito-core" % "1.9.5"
```

I assume it's right because I followed the play! doc.

so I launch activator and then the run command. This is what I got :

```
[AEC] $ run
[info] Updating file:/C:/Users/abefly/Desktop/workspace%20AEC/aec/AEC/}root...
[info] Resolving org.mockito#mockito-core_2.10;1.9.5 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.mockito#mockito-core_2.10;1.9.5
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\abefly\.ivy2\local\org.mockito\mockito-core_2.10\1.9.5\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\abefly\Desktop\workspace AEC\aec\AEC\repository\org.mockito\mockito-core_2.10\1.9.5\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mockito/mockito-core_2.10/1.9.5/mockito-core_2.10-1.9.5.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/mockito/mockito-core_2.10/1.9.5/mockito-core_2.10-1.9.5.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.mockito/mockito-core_2.10/1.9.5/ivys/ivy.xml
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.mockito#mockito-core_2.10;1.9.5: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]          org.mockito:mockito-core_2.10:1.9.5 (C:\Users\abefly\Desktop\workspace AEC\aec\AEC\build.sbt#L18-19)
[warn]            +- aec:aec_2.10:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.mockito#mockito-core_2.10;1.9.5: not found
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed 10 fÚvr. 2016 16:17:53
```

So i'm wondering what I've done wrong? Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
libraryDependencies += "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "1.9.5"
```

Note that there is only one percent sign.
Having two of them adds the Scala version to the download url of the library.

Comment: Why does activator tells me it downloaded it successfully and then telling me that it can't resolve the location of the library ?

Comment: Where/how does it say it downloaded it successfully? I don't see a message like this.